# Android intent filter with pathPattern matches in assistant but not work

Tags: android, deep-linking, applinks

I'm trying to make one app link to open our app instead the browser.

The app links Assistant tells me that the pattern works fine but when I try it on the emulator or physical device it doesn't work :(

Filter:

```
<activity android:name=".activities.AppLinksActivity">
         <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
             <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
             <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
             <data android:scheme="http"
                 android:host="www.emagister.com"
                 android:pathPattern="/.*-cursos-.*.htm"

                 />
         </intent-filter>
     </activity>
```

Url to match: http://www.emagister.com/curso-avanzado-lenguaje-programacion-javascript-cursos-2863146.htm

Assistant message:

[Assistant image pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aZ7xn.png)

But when I open it on the device or click run test i doesn't work and opens the browser.

If I put android:pathPattern="/juridico-master-compliance-officer-controller-juridico-empresarial-cursos-3299291.htm" in the manifest instead the above pathpattern everything works perfect.

What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Have you tried adding another data tag with https? i.e.                                  <data android:scheme="http" android:host="yoursite.com" />
    <data android:scheme="https" android:host="yoursite.com" />

Answer (score 1):

Your `pathPattern` regex seems unnecessarily complex; I don't believe it's documented which regex parser is used here, but I wouldn't be surprised if it's somehow choking on this.

Try simplifying as much as possible and then add elements back (but as few as possible). I suspect `pathPattern='.*cursos.*'` would still get you the same thing.

Comment: Thanks for the Answer Alex. I know it is pretty old. I think the OP wants to restrict strongly. That's why OP added a special symbol and other details. Can we add support for symbol check in regex?